# Validate the file structure after upload

Tags: php, json, validation, symfony

I'm using Symfony, and I have to fill my database after upload file form the user.

The file must have some keys ( JSON File ) and I have to validate each object before save it (file contains array of JSON object)

I'm using Option Resolver, but I don't know if this is a good idea, because if the file isn't conformed I get 500 error, I can't take the single "violation".

Maybe I have to use Validator, but I haven't Entity where apply the constraints or Class to map my object.

Which architecture I have to use to validate my upload file? Use optionResolver or Create entity to map my Object and add constraints?

Comment: Are you using Doctrine as well?

Comment: @marijnz0r no in this project I don't use Doctrine